# Error 8058 in Creating a product via xml in Amazon using Amzon MWS

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Im creating a product via xml in amazon using amazon MWS, I tested my xml in the amazon scratchpad.
Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
 <Header>
   <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
   <MerchantIdentifier>********</MerchantIdentifier>
 </Header>
 <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
 <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
 <Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
  <Product>
   <SKU>98765654356765498776565GTRF546</SKU>
   <StandardProductID>
    <Type>EAN</Type>
    <Value>45201187656</Value>
   </StandardProductID>
   <ProductTaxCode>A_TOY_GENERALL</ProductTaxCode>
   <Condition>
    <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
   </Condition>
   <NumberOfItems>10</NumberOfItems>
   <DescriptionData>
    <Title>Smartivity EDGE Jurassic Wonders Pack With Many Features </Title>
    <Brand>Smartivity</Brand>
    <Description>Smartivity EDGE LET’S LEARN and play 1,2,3… set includes 10</Description>
    <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="INR">410</MSRP>
    <Manufacturer>Smartivity Labss Pvt. Ltd.</Manufacturer>
    <MfrPartNumber>SMRT1025</MfrPartNumber>
    <ItemType>toy-figures</ItemType>
    <TargetAudience>Children</TargetAudience>
    <TargetAudience>unisex-adult</TargetAudience>
    <RecommendedBrowseNode>1350381031</RecommendedBrowseNode>
   </DescriptionData>
   <ProductData>
    <Toys>
     <ProductType>
      <ToysAndGames>
       <Color>Blue</Color>
       <ColorMap>Brown</ColorMap>
      </ToysAndGames>
     </ProductType>
     <AgeRecommendation>
      <MinimumManufacturerAgeRecommended unitOfMeasure="years">5</MinimumManufacturerAgeRecommended>
     </AgeRecommendation>
   </Toys>
  </ProductData>
 </Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I am getting this error.

> Some attributes are missing for SKU: [*****************].For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/errorcode/8058

Even if go through the above link it doesn't help much, I have given all the required fields for posting a "toys" product by seeing the Inventory File Templates here https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200186090.
I have downloaded Toys & Games template from the above link and gave all the required fields, then also the same error is coming.
Please help me to solve this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inventory file templates are a different process. If you want to use MWS - first look at the XML guide:

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.*V324496426*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V324496426_.pdf)

Next get the specific XSD for Toys which is linked in your Seller Central account. One consideration - does this product come in different colors or sizes? If yes then you will need to set up parent product / child products and include the variation data in your feed. 
http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200779220

========= edit

Honestly even with 50 products - I would just go into seller central and do them by hand. The errors that you get back when you are working in seller central admin are much clearer and easier to follow up on. Then once your products are listed all you have to do is keep up the inventory and any price changes and those feeds are very simple.

Versus the XML Product, Image, and Relationship feeds where you send them and then its a separate operation to send amazon the unique feed ids and get the results back. And then you have to parse the xml results feeds, match it with your skus, extract the warning and error messages, etc.

Of course the mws feeds are possible just expect some obstacles to get everything going. **Start with the minimum required fields first.** For relationships - look again at the link i posted above that outlines variation data and when it applies. However have to immediately put in the disclaimer that each (category) department is different so the only place to really be sure is in the XSD.

To generate XML from an XSD - there are different tools that you can download that will do this and most of them have a 30 day trial period. I have used Netbeans for this and it works. I want to try intellij idea tool to see if its any easier. But first google 'generate xml from xsd' so you get the correct edition of the software and see if there are any other tools more appropriate for you.

Finally look at the official mws board to see what issues have come up for people. This is also the only source of information if there is a temporary system level problem with MWS. https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=35

Comment: Yeah i got XSD for Toys from this link. https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/help/1611?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0&, Now how do i get to know weather it has relationship in that or not. and how do i generate the XML from this XSD?

Comment: added to my answer above

Comment: Thank u so much for the information. However I successfully added the product to the amazon using the xml, right now existing product on amazon is getting added by using the ASIN number.
- I'm trying to create the new product using the xml. This is not happening because of lack of attributes required for a product.

Comment: my suggestion would be - do one product directly in seller central product admin and see what the error is. then use that to help with your xml structure and whatever the required fields are. and if all else fails - ask for help through seller central :-)

Comment: I do added the product directly its going fine without errors, There is something called as Failed inventory in admin of amazon, my xml feed is going and storing there and its showing errors and required fields. In one of the feed I had not given Price and Quantity because I have to use different xml for this and feed type will also be different. So i gave Price xml for that particular product by using the same SKU it successfully took it, And then i gave Quantity xml but its not accepting it giving SKU does not exist error.